# relative URL from CSS angular 2

Tags: angular, relative-path

In angular 2, I am trying to provide background image to a division using .css file of component but relative path is throwing error.

**test.component.html**

```
<div class="release-bg"></div>
```

**test.component.css**

```
.release-bg{
        background-image: url("../assets/images/image release green@4x.png");
    }
```

**Error:**

```
Failed to compile.

./src/app/components/balldetails/balldetails.component.css
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError: H:\Hotstar-web\hotstar-web\src\app\components\balldetails\balldetails.component.css:385:29: Can't resolve '../assets/images/image%20release%20green@4x.png' in 'H:\Hotstar-web\hotstar-web\src\app\components\balldetails'

  383 |     }
  384 |     .release-bg{
> 385 |         background-image: url("../assets/images/image release green@4x.png");
      |                                ^
  386 |     }
  387 |     

 @ ./src/app/components/balldetails/balldetails.component.ts 22:21-59
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0 ./src/main.ts
```

Is this is not the right way to use relative path in angular 2? If not how can I proceed to make it work?

Please let me know if you need more info.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You Could probably provide the URL path from with in the Component file and use it in your HTML with below Property:

```
[style.background-image]="variableName/ your Component Class variable name here"
```

Inside Component.ts file declare your variable like below

```
variableName:any = 'url('+ your image folder relative path name +')';
```

Answer (score 0):

`"../assets/path/to/image/image.png"` should be `"assets/path/to/image/image.png"`, since the folder *assets* is listed by default within the *.angular-cli.json* as folder for assets (resources):

```
"assets": [
  "assets",
  "favicon.ico"
],
```

Btw, does `"../assets/images/image release green@4x.png"` contain spaces?

Comment: That is not OK. Angular should not expect developer to modify existing CSS files.

Answer (score 0):

Code should be like this

```
.release-bg{
        background-image: url("/assets/images/image release green@4x.png");
    }
```

Comment: This will break if site hosted not in root. Like "https://example.com/en-US/"